# Validation is not propagate to Custom Form Control ng-select in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-ngselect

I'm using Reactive Form with Custom Form Control in my Angular 9 application.

I wrapped my [ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) control with Custom Form Control.

And I have problem with validation. I set formControl to be required. [Documentation says](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#validation-state) that `ng-invalid` css class should be set to ng-select automatically. But in fact with custom form control it doesn't work properly. The css class is not set, but the wrapper class is. Am I doing something wrong or this is library issue?

Check stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmvttg-ex63ka?file=src/forms-single-select-example.component.html&fbclid=IwAR2robtd_15khTVhmW59lLhn21HOHl_yYTrCWKaPRmfUt1QVvUn3n8V4Vjo

Answer (score 3):

DiPix, the problem is that Angular add the control status CSS classes to your custom control, NOT to the ng-select that belong to your inner control

You can inject the ngControl and check about control.control.invalid and control.control.touched

```
constructor(private injector:Injector){}
ngOnInit()
{
   this.control = this.injector.get(NgControl);
}
```

then you can use some like

```
  <ng-select #mySelect  [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid':control?.control.invalid,
                                    'ng-touched':control?.control.touched}"
   ....>
```

Another aproach is ask about the class of the parent. So if you defined a getter like

```
get parentClass()
{
  const match = /class=\"(.*?)\">/.exec(this.element.nativeElement.parentElement.innerHTML);
  return match[0].split('"')[1]
}

constructor(private element:ElementRef){}
```

You can use

```
<ng-select #mySelect  [ngClass]="parentClass" 
  ...>
```

You can see in [your forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmvttg-3d6aad?file=src%2Fmy-control%2Fmy-control.component.html)

NOTE: Anyway, to wrapper a ng-select, is unnecesary create a custom form control, just a **simple component** with a @Input

```
@Input()control:any
```

And you use as

```
    <mycontrol [control]="someForm.get('someControl')"></mycontrol>
```

You can see how simple becomes in [this another stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmvttg-njxgck?file=src%2Fforms-single-select-example.component.html)

Comment: So basically when should I use Custom Form Control?

Comment: In my opinion, a Custom Form control is usefull if add a new apparence to a control. a datePicker is a good example of "custom form Control", a multi-select is another great example,or a gauge, or a combo that show a table when drop down, (I doubt about a input with mask) or.... If only want to "group" inputs e.g. a card-credit that ask about number, expiration date and CVC -even if show the card type- or a group of adress with street, city, country and CP, I prefer use a component. But really it's only a **personal opinion**. I'm only a amateur in Angular

Comment: Make sense for me. But I've got small problem. I have directive that looking for `formControlName` attribute `this.hostElement.nativeElement.nextElementSibling.attributes.formControlName` now such element is not exist as I'm using `[control]` which is not shown on DOM. Any idea how can i get controlName?

Answer (score -1):

You can fix this by passing the `FormGroup` down into your subcomponent via `Input` and set it to the `ng-select`:

```
<mycontrol formControlName="someControl" [parentFormGroup]="someForm" ></mycontrol>
```

Component:

```
export class MyControlComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() parentFormGroup: FormGroup;
...
```

Template:

```
<ng-select #mySelect
           [formGroup]="parentFormGroup"
...
```