# Both markAllAsTouched and markAsTouched don't affect subforms

Tags: angular, angular-forms

## Background information

I have a **VERY** large form (potentially hundreds of fields) that I decided to break into smaller sub-form components (for obvious reasons). I achieved this using Control Value Accessors. This worked like a charm until it came time to show errors on fields at submit.

The sub-forms are structured like this:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <app-subform [documentId]="documentId" formControlName="sub-form"></app-subform>

  <!-- Other form fields here ... -->
</form>
```

To ease my work I created an error component that takes as input a control like in the code below. The code below is part of the sub-form.

```html
<div class="question">
  <label for="tableNumber">
    Figure/table number
    <app-required [type]="'conditional'"></app-required>
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="tableNumber" formControlName="figure"/>
  <app-error [control]="form.get('figure')"></app-error>
</div>
```

The inside of my error HTML looks something like this:

```html
<span class="errorWrapper" *ngIf="control.invalid && control.touched" (click)="clearError()" [innerHtml]="error"></span>
```

## Example code

While I can't quite share my full code, here's a reproduction of the problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/encapsulated-sub-forms

## The Problem

When I submit my code, in order to get error messages displaying across every input, I mark all inputs as touched using `this.form.markAllAsTouched();`. While this works like a charm for the inputs that are not part of sub-form components, the sub-form components themselves don't react at at all, remaining untouched.

## Solutions I considered

- My first reaction was - why not mark each control individually as touched? *Doesn't work*
- How about I implement an input for each sub-form component that triggers mark as touched? *Didn't try, seems more like a hack than a best-practice solution*
- Change my implementation to use `ControlContainer`. *Seems the most promising*

## What I tried

I tried changing the implementation to use `ControlContainer` but that comes with its own set of challenges (described in a separate stack overflow question).

## My question

So basically, what I want to know is, how can I get my sub-form inputs to show errors on submit, following best practices and with a minimal amount of rewrite (my priorities being in that order)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that your sub-form component is declaring a brand new `FormGroup` instance. It knows nothing of the `FormGroup` instance in the parent control.

My approach here would be to pass nested form groups within the root `FormGroup` from the parent through to the sub-forms.

This would allow your sub-forms to update the form group in the parent without the need for two-way binding. And the events triggered on the form group would propagate through the sub forms.

**Example code**

parent.component.ts

```js
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  subGroup1: this.formBuilder.group({}),
  subGroup1: this.formBuilder.group({})
});
```

parent.component.html

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <app-sub-form-1 [form]="form.get('subGroup1')"></app-sub-form-1>
  <app-sub-form-2 [form]="form.get('subGroup2')"></app-sub-form-1>
</form>
```

sub-form1.component.ts

```js
this.form.addControl('sub-group1-control1', new FormControl(''));
```

Answer (score 3):

it's logic, the control touched is `form.get('subForm')`. 
And sorry I can not find a good solution about this. I never understand why create a custom form control when the more easy is use a component, see, e.g. [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60459025/validation-is-not-propagate-to-custom-form-control-ng-select-in-angular/60467058#60467058) or [this post from Tomas Trajan](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/angular-reactive-sub-forms-type-safe-without-duplication-dbd24225e1e8)

I suggest this aproach, else you need make a method in each custom form control to markAll as touched and called from parent

Comment: Eventually, this is exactly what I ended up doing. I declared an interface which has a markFormAsTouched function that does what it says. I made each of my subforms implement the interface and then called the function using ViewChild.

Comment: Hi @TudorMerlas, do you have any code example from waht you explained about adding interface ?